# Get value of child

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I would like to get the value of `image`.

I already have the UID of the user but when my code runs I get this error: `Error: No such object: XXXXX.appspot.com/https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com/images/-M9OeGPXB-KqEVqxZYCb/image`

And I don't understand why because the value is not null.

Screenshot of my database : 
[image]

My code :

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://XXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "gs://XXXXX.appspot.com",
});

var defaultStorage = admin.storage();

// Cut off time. Child nodes older than this will be deleted.
const CUT_OFF_TIME = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 24 Hours in milliseconds.

/**
 * This database triggered function will check for child nodes that are older than the
 * cut-off time. Each child needs to have a `timestamp` attribute.
 */
exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/images/{pushId}').onWrite(async (change) => {
  const ref = change.after.ref.parent; // reference to the parent
  const now = Date.now();
  const cutoff = now - CUT_OFF_TIME;
  const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);
  const snapshot = await oldItemsQuery.once('value');


  snapshot.forEach((child) => {

        const uid = child.key;
        const re = admin.database().ref('images/'+uid);
        const img = re.child('image');

        const bucket = defaultStorage.bucket();
        const file = bucket.file(img);

    // Delete the file
        return file.delete();
    })


  // create a map with all children that need to be removed
  const updates = {};
  snapshot.forEach(child => {
    updates[child.key] = null;
  });
  // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
  return ref.update(updates);
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `img` variable is just a reference to the property in the database. If you call `toString()` on that is returns the full path to that reference, which is `https://yourprojct.firebaseio.com/path/to/property`.

So you'll want to actually use the value from the database, and the use *that* in to find the file in storage:

```
snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    const uid = child.key;
    const img = child.child('image');
    console.log(img.val());
```

Now this will log the path to the image, as it's stored in your database.